# How to pass HTML inputs to a java file

Tags: java, html

I'm in a post AP level high school computer science class and am working on a group project where we need to utilize microsoft outlook calendar API to populate the calendar with information given from an HTML form. We don't know exactly where to start in terms of how we can get the information provided in the HTML file to be transferred into our java program which is supposed to process the information and populate the outlook calendar. Here is a copy of our html file, the goal is to send the information given by the user to the html form, to our java file for processing:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Accomodation Request Form</title>
 <style type="text/css">   
  body{font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;}
  #container {width:300px; margin:0 auto;}
  form label {display:inline-block; width:140px}

  form input[type="text"],
  form input[type="password"],
  form input[type="email"] 
  {width:160px;}

  form .line {clear:both;}
  form .line.submit {text-align:right;}
 </style>
</head>
 <body>
  <h1>Accomodation Request Form</h1>
  <form action="email.php" name="EC Form" method="post">
  <table>
  <tr>
   <td>First name:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" required="true" placeholder="Firstname"></td>   </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Last name:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="lastname"id="lastname" required="true" placeholder="Lastname"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Student ID:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="ID"id="ID" required="true" placeholder="ID"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Course Name:</td>
   <td><select name="course">
   <option value="Advanced Projects">Advanced Projects</option>
   <option value="AP US History">AP US History</option>
   </select>
   </td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Course Teacher:</td>
   <td><select name="teacher">
   <option value="Mr. Srock">Mr. Srock</option>
   <option value="Mr. Alcorn">Mr. Alcorn</option>
   </select>
   </td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Test Period:</td>
   <td><select name="period">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Accommodations Requested:</td>
   <td><textarea name="Accommodations" rows="4" cols="20" id="Accommodations" required="true" placeholder="Accommodations"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Student Email:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name = "email" id="email" required="true" placeholder="Email"></td>
  </tr>
   <td><input type="submit" value="Send"></td>
   <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/`

Comment: Servlets are correct. Since this seems like a pretty small project, I'd recommend using Spring Boot. http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

Comment: SpringMVC is based on Servlets, you will need to handle HTTP POST request. And as mentioned project could be SpringBoot project. You can check other MVC frameworks and not only in Java if you like. You can use Node.js http server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it using jsp too.
Steps can be :

1. Create A jsp page
2. In your HTML file, in form tag, pass the jsp page in the 'action'
3. Receive your information on jsp using `request.getParameter(parameterName);` method.
4. At jsp page, call a constructor of the java file and pass the parameter to the constructor.( For this you have to define a parameterized constructor in your java code.)

This will simply transfer your data from an HTML page to your java file in a few lines of code.

Comment: Easiest answer on the web!